# Recording And Broadcasting Http Live Stream With .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webrtc, http-live-streaming

I want to implement a live stream captures from mobile phone camera or captures from display screen and I use `.NetCore` and `WebRTC` and `ffmpeg` to have a hls live stream on the sever and broadcast it through the http to multi users.
The schematics looklike this:

`WebRTC (camera/display screen)` ==> `.NetCore Server` ==> `FFMPEG (Transcoding)` ==> `HLS Stream`

I read some articles, but I don't know how can I send data from webrtc and receive it with asp.net.

How can I implement this structure?

Does that structure a right structure in terms of cost or this solution can't be right?

Can anyone help me about having live recording and broadcasting stream?

Comment: See following : https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/manual/cs/cs.html

Comment: This example https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/tree/master/examples/WebRTCReceiver has a prototype of how to receive a WebRTC stream with dotnet (it wraps the ffmpeg libraries it requires but there's no transcoding). Doesn't help with the HLS part.

Comment: Found any solution ? I am also looking for it I Just want to record and live stream the video on website